# How can I get a branch name on a closed pull request?

Tags: github-actions

Github actions doesn't seem to expose the branch name on closed pull requests. Does anybody know of a workaround ? The below action file produces the following error: `Error: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/1365/merge`

```
name: Close Pull Request

# only trigger on pull request closed events
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]

jobs:
  merge_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1.0.0
      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
        id: extract_branch
      - name: Delete Namespace
        run: ./bin/delete_namespace.sh ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}
  close_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1.0.0
      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
        id: extract_branch
      - name: Delete Namespace
        run: ./bin/delete_namespace.sh ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from `github.event`

```
PR src: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
PR dst: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
```

```
name: Close Pull Request

# only trigger on pull request closed events
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]

jobs:
  merge_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1.0.0
      - name: Delete Namespace
        run: ./bin/delete_namespace.sh ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
  close_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1.0.0
      - name: Delete Namespace
        run: ./bin/delete_namespace.sh ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
```